# How can I change URL without refreshing page like Google+?

Tags: javascript, html

When I was examining Google+, I'm surprized when I see usage of URLs. Google profile URLs change without refresing page. For example this is a photos tab URL: https://plus.google.com/104560124403688998123/photos When you click Videos tab, URL exactly goes to https://plus.google.com/104560124403688998123/videos without refreshing page. How Google coders success this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the history object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Especially history.pushState and history.replaceState

(Should mention that this only works in modern browsers, for old ones use hashes).

Comment: Yes, but the History API only lets you go to where the user has already gone to. (Go forward and backward in the user's browsing history). How does Gmail let you go to pages you haven't gone to yet (New emails) without refreshing and change the URL?

Answer (score 1):

This is about HTML 5. take a look at "onpopstate event".  For further information go to the link. http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pushState.
You can change the URL to another URL within the same domain, but can not change the domain for security reasons.In Javascript, you can use.

window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);

Object and string is your domain ex. www.google.co.in
title you can give whats you want.
and lastly you place new url ex. 'webhp?source=search_app'

ex. window.history.pushState(“www.google.co.in”, “Google”, “/webhp?source=search_app”);

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a hash. This is not how google does it, but it doesn't force a refresh. In Javascript, you can use

```
parent.location.hash = "Text";
```

so that the URL will be http://yoursite.com/yourpage#text

Edit: This seems to be new to Google+. GMail uses a hash like

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/130f48da33c5330
```

Comment: I know hash method, but Google+ method seems so good and interesting. Because I thought that it was impossible.

Comment: He's specifically asking for the method shown in his question that does NOT use hashes, but changes the actual URL.